# Getting Empty Index In Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to find the index value of a row using pandas but when I use the below code it gives me an empty index. However, the index value of the row is 104.
[image]

```
print(dframe[dframe['Num1'] == 'abort_suite_on_crash'].index.values)
```

Comment: Strange, Test if  `dframe['Num1'].iloc[104] == 'abort_suite_on_crash'`?

Comment: it gives False as a result.

Comment: May be there are some spaces at beginning  or some not printable characters.

Comment: oh man not sure how to deal with it

Comment: but when i use 104 index for find the value it gives the correct result

Comment: "but when i use 104 index for find the value it gives the correct result"(1) seems in contradiction with "it gives False as a result."(2).
As (2) shows, you have a data problem not a code problem: Thus, you need investigate the data. Moreover you need to understand from where the problem comes from to define a strategy to cope with it.